# Dynamics 365 - Plugin Does Not Update Values

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have been chasing this down since yesterday, and nothing makes sense.  I have gone through various permutations of what the code can look like - changed the Decimal type function to String and returned a String instead of a decimal, Used the decimal number, hard coding the value within the if statement (not using a variable), and using the variable itself, but nothing seems to work.  If I just set the fields value in the beginning of the try block, and don't do any type of logic, the fields are being udpdated.  As I step through the code via Plugin Profiles/Debug in plugin registration tool, I can see that the lines of code to set the values are being hit, and no exceptions are being thrown, but again, the values are not being updated.  I even tried to add the service.Update(entity); but that did not work either (and when I set the values of the fields without any logic, I did not need the service.Update call to save the values).

The field I am trying to write to in CRM is of Decimal type with 2 precision.  Of course, decimal types in C# are of 8 or 10 precision, so I have even tried to trim the decimal, convert the decimal to a string, etc etc- but nothing works.

Any ideas to help me figure out what's going on here?

I have posted the *simplest* version of my code right here- before I went and changed the Decimal type function to string, etc.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;




namespace ClientNTE
{
    public class UpdateVals : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));


            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {

                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));


                try
                {
                    //Get current record's GUID, which will always be in the attributes collection
                    Guid MainEntityID = new Guid(entity["msdyn_workorderid"].ToString());

                    //Get related entity record's GUID from generic field value grabber function against the main entity

                    Guid RefEntityID = GetGUIDFieldValueFrmID(service, "msdyn_workorder", "msdyn_workorderid", MainEntityID, "msdyn_agreement");

                    //if it has a value, continue

                    if (RefEntityID != Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        Decimal RefEntityFieldValue = GetDecFieldValueFrmID(service, "msdyn_agreement", "msdyn_agreementid", RefEntityID, "client_ntepercent");

                        //if it has a value, continue

                        if (RefEntityFieldValue > -99999999)
                        {
                            entity["client_ntepercent"] = RefEntityFieldValue;
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //write errors to the CRM Plugin Trace Log
                    tracingService.Trace("clientNTE - Agreement To Work Order - ", ex.ToString());
                    //Throw error through UI
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Error, Please See Plugin Log");
                }
            }
        }

        public Guid GetGUIDFieldValueFrmID(IOrganizationService svc, String EntityNm, String EntityIDField, Guid EntityIDValue, String ReturnFieldNm)
        {
            Guid retval = Guid.Empty;

            try
            {
                OrganizationServiceContext orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(svc);

                var ReturnRecords = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery(EntityNm)
                                    where (Guid)a[EntityIDField] == EntityIDValue
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        FieldVal = a[ReturnFieldNm]
                                    };

                if (ReturnRecords != null)
                {
                    foreach (var EvalRec in ReturnRecords)
                    {
                        retval = ((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference)EvalRec.FieldVal).Id;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    retval = Guid.Empty;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retval = Guid.Empty;
                //Throw error through UI
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.ToString());
            }

            return retval;
        }

        public Decimal GetDecFieldValueFrmID(IOrganizationService svc, String EntityNm, String EntityIDField, Guid EntityIDValue, String ReturnFieldNm)
        {
            Decimal retval = -99999999;

            try
            {
                OrganizationServiceContext orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(svc);

                var ReturnRecords = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery(EntityNm)
                                    where (Guid)a[EntityIDField] == EntityIDValue
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        FieldVal = a[ReturnFieldNm]
                                    };

                if (ReturnRecords != null)
                {
                    foreach (var EvalRec in ReturnRecords)
                    {
                        retval = Convert.ToDecimal(EvalRec.FieldVal);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    retval = -99999999;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retval = -99999999;
                //Throw error through UI
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.ToString());
            }

            return retval;
        }

        //public static Boolean UpdateParentRecord(IOrganizationService svc, Guid ParentRecordID, String FieldValue)
        //{

        //    Boolean retval = false;

        //    try
        //    {
        //        Entity parent_entityrec = new Entity("parent_entity");

        //        parent_entityrec["fieldtoupdate"] = FieldValue;

        //        svc.Update(parent_entityrec);

        //        retval = true;

        //    }

        //    catch (Exception ex)
        //    {
        //        retval = false;
        //    }

        //    return retval;

        //}
    }
}
```

Now, here you can see my current code, where I am doing a bunch of crazy stuff - First, using a String type function to get the decimal value back.  Second, calling a function to actually set the value, just to prove that there's not something wrong with the existing function (and to allow for easier formatting down the line).  No matter what I do, I can't get this dang thing to  work!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;



namespace CLIENTNTE
{
    public class AgreementToWorkOrder : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));


            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {

                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));


                try
                {
                    //string Num = 12.500000.ToString();
                    //entity["CLIENT_testdecimal"] = Num;
                    //entity["CLIENT_ntepercent"] = Num;

                    //Get current record's GUID, which will always be in the attributes collection
                    Guid MainEntityID = new Guid(entity["msdyn_workorderid"].ToString());

                    //Get related entity record's GUID from generic field value grabber function against the main entity

                    Guid RefEntityID = GetGUIDFieldValueFrmID(service, "msdyn_workorder", "msdyn_workorderid", MainEntityID, "msdyn_agreement");

                    //if it has a value, continue

                    if (RefEntityID != Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        String RefEntityFieldValue = GetDecFieldValueFrmID(service, "msdyn_agreement", "msdyn_agreementid", RefEntityID, "CLIENT_ntepercent");

                        decimal decVal = Convert.ToDecimal(RefEntityFieldValue);
                        //if it has a value, continue
                        if (decVal > -99999999)
                        {
                            // entity["CLIENT_ntepercent"] = RefEntityFieldValue;
                            // entity["CLIENT_ntepercent"] = "12.5";// RefEntityFieldValue;
                            //entity["CLIENT_testdecimal"] = "13.5";// RefEntityFieldValue;
                            setDecimal(RefEntityFieldValue, serviceProvider);
                            //service.Update(entity);
                        } 
                    }

                } 
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //write errors to the CRM Plugin Trace Log
                    tracingService.Trace("CLIENTNTE - Agreement To Work Order - ", ex.ToString());
                    //Throw error through UI
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Error, Please See Plugin Log");
                }
            }
        }

        public void setDecimal(String RefEntityFieldValue, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            //IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            //IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            //ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            //Guid MainEntityID = new Guid(entity["msdyn_workorderid"].ToString());
            //Guid RefEntityID = GetGUIDFieldValueFrmID(service, "msdyn_workorder", "msdyn_workorderid", MainEntityID, "msdyn_agreement");

            //String RefEntityFieldValue = GetDecFieldValueFrmID(service, "msdyn_agreement", "msdyn_agreementid", RefEntityID, "CLIENT_ntepercent"); */

            // entity["CLIENT_testdecimal"] = RefEntityFieldValue;
            entity["CLIENT_testdecimal"] = 12;
            entity["CLIENT_ntepercent"] = RefEntityFieldValue;


        }

        public Guid GetGUIDFieldValueFrmID(IOrganizationService svc, String EntityNm, String EntityIDField, Guid EntityIDValue, String ReturnFieldNm)
        {
            Guid retval = Guid.Empty;

            try
            {
                OrganizationServiceContext orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(svc);

                var ReturnRecords = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery(EntityNm)
                                    where (Guid)a[EntityIDField] == EntityIDValue
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        FieldVal = a[ReturnFieldNm]
                                    };

                if (ReturnRecords != null)
                {
                    foreach (var EvalRec in ReturnRecords)
                    {
                        retval = ((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference)EvalRec.FieldVal).Id;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    retval = Guid.Empty;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retval = Guid.Empty;

                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.ToString());
            }

            return retval;
        }

        public String GetDecFieldValueFrmID(IOrganizationService svc, String EntityNm, String EntityIDField, Guid EntityIDValue, String ReturnFieldNm)
        {
            Decimal retval = -99999999;
            String stringVal = "";

            try
            {
                OrganizationServiceContext orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(svc);

                var ReturnRecords = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery(EntityNm)
                                    where (Guid)a[EntityIDField] == EntityIDValue
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        FieldVal = a[ReturnFieldNm]
                                    };

                if (ReturnRecords != null)
                {
                    foreach (var EvalRec in ReturnRecords)
                    {
                        retval = Convert.ToDecimal(EvalRec.FieldVal);
                        // stringVal = retval.ToString().TrimEnd('0', '.');
                        stringVal = retval.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    retval = -99999999;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retval = -99999999;
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.ToString());
            }

            return stringVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Any and all input appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if your plugin step was not registered to run post operation? I couldn't see a call to the IOrganizationService.Update method so I assume this was intendend to be pre operation.

Comment: I should have included more context about my plugin in the original post, my bad.  It runs OnCreate of Work Orders, never on Update, and just pulls data down from the Agreement (parent) to populate the WO (child).  The OOB mapping didn't work, and using Workflows got in the way of other onChange plugin logic for the Work Order entity, so I had to break it out into its own piece of code. This is registered as a pre-validation plugin (I am all for changing that - I still do not have full understanding of pre-val, pre-op, post-op).

Answer (score 0):

My response is based upon the following assumptions about your code:

1. The use case is that when the an msdyn_workorder record is created with a value in the msdyn_agreement field, the client_ntepercent value on the work order should be set to the value of client_ntepercent on the agreement.
2. The plugin is registered in the Pre-Operation stage for the Create message on the msdyn_workorder entity.

The proposed fix requires the following changes:

1. The code needs to get the msdyn_agreement value from the target entity instead of executing a retrieve query since the work order has not yet been saved to the database.

The reason for your issue may have been that you are querying the work order record to get the agreement value from a pre-operation plugin.  The work order won't be saved in the database yet.

Updated Code:

```
public class UpdateVals : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity && 
            context.PreEntityImages != null && context.PreEntityImages.Contains("PreImage"))
        {
            Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            try
            {
                //Get current record's GUID, which will always be in the attributes collection
                Guid MainEntityID = target.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("msdyn_workorderid");

                EntityReference RefEntityID = null;
                if (target.Attributes.Contains("msdyn_agreement"))
                {
                    RefEntityID = target.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("msdyn_agreement");
                }

                //if it has a value, continue
                if (RefEntityID != null)
                {
                    Decimal RefEntityFieldValue = GetDecFieldValueFrmID(service, "msdyn_agreement", "msdyn_agreementid", RefEntityID.Id, "client_ntepercent");

                    //if it has a value, continue
                    if (RefEntityFieldValue > -99999999)
                    {
                        target["client_ntepercent"] = RefEntityFieldValue;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //write errors to the CRM Plugin Trace Log
                tracingService.Trace("clientNTE - Agreement To Work Order - ", ex.ToString());
                //Throw error through UI
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Error, Please See Plugin Log");
            }
        }
    }

    public Decimal GetDecFieldValueFrmID(IOrganizationService svc, String EntityNm, String EntityIDField, Guid EntityIDValue, String ReturnFieldNm)
    {
        Decimal retval = -99999999;

        try
        {
            OrganizationServiceContext orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(svc);

            var ReturnRecords = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery(EntityNm)
                                where (Guid)a[EntityIDField] == EntityIDValue
                                select new
                                {
                                    FieldVal = a[ReturnFieldNm]
                                };

            if (ReturnRecords != null)
            {
                foreach (var EvalRec in ReturnRecords)
                {
                    retval = Convert.ToDecimal(EvalRec.FieldVal);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retval = -99999999;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retval = -99999999;
            //Throw error through UI
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.ToString());
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through that, especially because I had some missing information in my code.  Also, your name sounds familiar, like we may have worked together in the past or something......Anywho.. As I stated above, for now at least, this is simply running OnCreate of WO, and pulls the data down from Agreement to WO.  Once it has been created, we don't want to update the data again from the agreement (we want the agreement:wo relationship to be a 'point in time' - which the users can also update as required).  I am going to pull your code into VS now and test er out. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianFrick Thanks for the additional information.  I will update the answer based on the plugin being only for create.  The issue should be the same.  Querying for the work order in pre-create will find nothing since the work order has not been saved to the database yet.  However, in create there is no pre-image, so you can just get the agreement value from the target.